# What does a change in the mean pressure across 750 km indicate/signify?

Tags: meteorology, climate, barometric-pressure, pacific

Coming from the aviation site: [What is the westerly index?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/86529/14897)

The *westerly index* is:

> ... the Trenberth Z1 index ([Trenberth 1976](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Fluctuations%20and%20trends%20in%20indices%20of%20the%20Southern%20Hemisphere%20circulation.&author=K.%20E.%20Trenberth&publication_year=1976&volume=102&pages=65-75)), which is the departure of the monthly mean pressure difference between Auckland and Christchurch (near 44°S) from its mean over the 1961–90 period.
>
> — [journals.ametsoc.org](https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/apme/46/5/jam2491.1.xml)

Those two places are ~750 km apart (not a small distance), and [judging by the METAR reports](https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=nzaa,nzch&format=raw&hours=0&taf=off&layout=on), the QNH difference in the past 72 hours varies from 4 to 7 millibars or so. Is that unusual? What's the significance of that index?